# What is the difference between package description and package option?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, packages

[image]
I am making an ECG sensor schematic on EAGLE and I am concerned if this is something I should be taking into account while designing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last part of the part number indicates how the devices are delivered, tape-and-reel, waffle tray etc.  The devices themselves are identical.  There’s also the commercial vs industrial temperature range, but the footprint and function are the same for both.

Comment: If you look carefully at the package drawings, you will see that one package has a larger thermal pad, and shorter pads, than the other.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between package description and package option is the same difference between part numbers and part descriptions.

The latter describes what the package is in human terms and the former is a unique identifier so that you can refer exactly to it.

Answer (score 1):

That part is available in two different packages - the packages are described on the page before that table.  The table gives the ordering codes for the two package types.

You will have to decide which package to use (or which one is available to you) to determine the required footprint to put on your PC board.